# False friends et Faux amis

Tags: anglais, faux-amis

> **Cette question a été verrouillée pour empêcher l'ajout de réponses supplémentaires**
> Cependant, n'hésitez pas à ajouter de nouveaux faux amis au wiki

What are your worst (or most common) false friends?

The goal of this question is to make a list of the false friends from a French perspective : translation from French to English.

---

Quel est votre pire faux ami ?

L'idée de cette question est de rassembler le plus de faux amis français > anglais possibles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- *Blesser* (fr) : hurt/injure (en) **vs.** *Bless* (en) : bénir (fr)
- *Habit* (fr) : clothes (en) **vs.** *Habit* (en) : habitude (fr)
- *Ensuite* (fr) : Then (en) **vs.** *Ensuite* (bathroom) (en) : Salle de bains attenante (fr)
- *Coin* (fr) : corner (en) **vs.** *Coin* (en) : pièce de monnaie (fr)
- *Fonction* (dans une organisation) (fr) : office (en) **vs.** *Function* (en) : rôle (fr) cérémonie officielle (fr)
- *Fournitures* (fr) : supplies (en) **vs.** *Furniture* (en) : meubles (fr)
- *Avertissement* (fr) : warning (en) **vs.** *Advertisement* (en) : publicité (fr)
- *Commander* (passer une commande) (fr) : order (en) **vs.** *Command* (EN) = donner un ordre (fr)
- [Terrible](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/terrible#en): négatif en anglais et a généralement une connotation positive en français.
- *Éventuellement* (fr) : possibly (en) **vs.** *eventually* (en) : finalement (fr)
- *Actuellement* (fr) : at the present time (en) **vs.** *actually* (en) : en fait (fr)
- Evidence (en) : *indice*, *élément de preuve* (fr) ; *c'est une évidence* (fr) : it's obvious (en) ; *c'est bien mis en évidence* (fr) : it's visible/it's conspicuous (en)
- *Dresse* (fr) : stand / draw up (en) **vs.** *dress* (en) : habiller (fr)
- *Sensible* (fr) : sensitive (en) **vs.** *sensible* (en) : sensé (fr)
- *Tu me manques* (fr): **I** miss **you** (en). Inversion du sujet et complément
- *Assister à qqch.* (fr) : to attend (an event), to participate (en) **vs.** *assister qqn./qqch.* (fr) : *assist smb./smth.* (en)
- *Passer un examen* (fr) : to take an exam (en) **vs.** *réussir un examen* (fr) : *to pass an exam* (en)
- *Patron* (fr) : boss (en) **vs.** *Patron* (en) : client (fr)
- *Verge* (fr) : penis (en) **vs.** *Verge* (en) : bord, côté (fr)
- *Demande* (fr) : request (en) **vs.** *Demand* (en) : exigeance (fr)
- *Fabrique* (fr) : factory (en) **vs.** *Fabric* (en) : tissu (fr)

False friends et faux amis in specific domains:

- in Mathematics, *positif* (fr) : non-negative (en) **vs.** *positive* (en) : strictement positif (fr).
- in Physics, *flux* (fr) : flowrate (en) **vs.** *flux* (en) : densité de flux (fr)

Proverbes similaires, significations différentes :

- Ce n’est pas à un vieux singe que l’on apprend à faire des grimaces
      *(the old monkee knows them all from its vast experience of life)* **vs.**
  You can’t teach an old dog new tricks
      *(le vieux chien ne veux plus apprendre et ne s’en donnera pas la peine)*