# J'ai passé ou j'ai pris

Tags: usage

Quelle phrase ci-dessous est correcte ? Donnez-moi une explication, s'il vous plaît.

1. J'ai passé mon examen en avril dernier.
2. J'ai pris mon examen en avril dernier.

Comment: In France, I've never heard «j'ai pris mon examen». Bear in mind that you can «passer un examen» and fail it: «passer» is not «to pass».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Passer un examen* is translated in English as *take an exam*.](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/take+an+exam.html) Neither *passer* nor *take* are used here in their literal sense, which is why translating the expression word by word is misleading.

Note that English *pass an exam* is translated to French as *réussir un examen*. One could say that *passer un examen* and *pass an exam* is a [False friend / faux ami](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1444/9870).